# Phantomjs Cannot capture HTTP url with Custom Port

Tags: javascript, http, port, phantomjs

I am using Phantomjs in order to capture the content of a web page. I have tried it with lots of sites (i.e. Google, etc, etc) and it works perfectly. Then I tried to capture the content of a page that is under a dev server. This page listens to port 8080, and the capturing is not working.

Specifically the problem I get is: Unable to load address.

Does anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Apologies, wrong editing :) Please see updated question.

Comment: Can you specify the address you are using, the phantomjs command you are using, the nature of the network env you are in, etc.

Comment: I am using the rasterize.js from the examples in the phantomjs library. The command I am executing is the following: phantomjs rasterize.js http://mydomain.com:8080 /tmp/capture.pdf A4